# jQuery next (ish) selector

Tags: jquery

I've been banging my head against a wall with this code all morning and finaly decided to come here for some help.

I have the following markup.

```
<h3 class="element-title">Summary <span class="cs">THIS IS AN IMAGE</span></h3>

<textarea class="edit-mode" id="summary-<?php echo($randomId); ?>"><?php echo(br2nl($erow['summary'])); ?></textarea>
```

And the folliwing Jquery.

```
$(".cs").live('click',function() {
var element=$(this);
```

`var sc=element.prev(1).next('.edit-mode');`
  `alert(sc.toSource());`
 `});`

What I am trying to do is when the  is clicked for it to return the ID or even the object of the textarea below it. Unfortunately the page is very dynamic so I have to select on the classname of ".edit-mode" so referencing on ID is not an option - If it was I would be doing it.

THe problem I think lyes in that the span is inside the `<h3>` tag so I have to go out of it and then `next()` but doing that doesnt work.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Alex

Comment: Please accept an answer that you feel has helped you the most. You should do this because it provides valuable feedback to the answerers. You can do this by clicking the check mark next to the answer you found most helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pure guess, but would

```
var sc=element.closest('h3').next('.edit-mode:eq(0)'); alert(sc.get(0).id; });
```

do it for you?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried something like:

```
$(".cs").live('click',function() 
{
    var element=$(this);
    var sc = element.parent().next('textarea.edit-mode'); 
    alert(sc.toSource());
}
```

Comment: @Alex: you should accept answers that helped, so the users keep motivated to help you!